# What is the advantage of non-inverting op amp high pass filter

Tags: operational-amplifier, filter

The non-inverting op amp high-pass filter (first picture below) has a unity gain limit close to DC, while inverting op amp high-pass filter (second picture below) doesn't have such a limit. So why do people still use the non-inverting high-pass configuration?

[image]
[image]

Comment: shva, are you sure that the primary purpose of the shown circuits is high pass filtering? I ask this because both circuits are based on the classical principle for providing a suitable bias point in case of single supply. IMO it is very uncommon to use such an opamp based circuit for a first-order filtering. In addition, the circuits provide a very "bad" highpass filtering.

Comment: The first circuit is a shelving filter, not an HPF

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a reason non-inverting 1st order high-pass filters are sometimes used and this is to preserve the dc level in the circuit. It's horses for courses - some designs will want to preserve the DC level, some won't care and some won't want to. It's not a black and white sort of thing.

When it comes to a 2nd order high-pass filter the non-inverting configuration (Sallen Key type) will usually be preferred and this doesn't preserve the dc level: -

[image]

Again horses for courses.

Comment: Some interesting euphemisms there Andy!

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://www.researchgate.net/post/Why_are_inverting_op_amp_amplifiers_used_in_most_cases_instead_of_non_inverting_amplifiers) they talk about it. Several points they raised were:

> unlike a non-inverting OP-amplifier which has a minimum possible gain
>   of 1, an inverting Op-amp can be used as an attenuater with a gain
>   less than 1 as well.

and

> input impedance of non-inverting op-amp is infinite while that of
>   Inverting op-amp it is equal to the resistance between the input and
>   the inverting terminal, so a better impedance matching can be
>   obtained.

[This site](http://langster1980.blogspot.com/2012/10/op-amps-and-inverting-and-non-inverting.html) has good scope outputs to show you more info, and they sum it up by:

> the bandwidth response of an inverting amplifier is better over a
>   longer range.  That means that you could use the amplifier with a
>   better range frequencies of input signals.

Comment: Quote 2 is tortuously close to irrelevant (I'm trying really hard to think of a circumstance when this opportunity may be valid). Quote 3 means what exactly? What is bandwidth response? What is a better range of frequencies?

Comment: Also, you first quote is from a question that relates to non-inverting amplifiers without a mention of it being a filter. This then becomes a misleading answer in my opinion and because the OP has accepted an answer that is basically flawed on all three quotes I have to down-vote so that others coming along later may not be as easily persuaded it is a decent answer.

Comment: The gain-bandwidth product of an op amp doesn't differentiate between inverting and non-inverting amps as far as I'm aware so how can an inverting amplifier give a better frequency range response? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gain–bandwidth_product

Comment: How about the fact that the answers are out there... a simple search showed few relevant answers. No need to bash at me for "quoting"

Comment: @Andyaka Wanting a filter with a high input impedance is common to avoid modifying some previous stage, introducing distortion, etc.  However the input impedance of a non-inverting filter is not infinite, as it says.  For a Sallen Key lowpass filter it drops with frequency, for instance.